# Correct HTML5 mark up for headings in an ordered list

Tags: html

My content is like the following. (Ive only included the first 2 of 3).

```
1 
Get in touch
Get in touch with us to discuss your requirements.

2
Choose a service
One of our agents will aid you in choosing from our range of services.
```

So in other words:

```
Number
Heading
Text
```

How can I mark this up? I think this should be an ordered list. Can I put a heading in an ordered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. You place the heading in the list item, then any paragraphs that follow, within the same list item (I'm just using `<h2>` as an example):

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>Get in touch</h2>
        <p>Get in touch with us to discuss your requirements.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Choose a service</h2>
        <p>One of our agents will aid you in choosing from our range of services.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- Third item -->
    </li>
</ol>
```

The heading needs to reside within the list item and not directly in the ordered list itself for the markup to be valid. It also makes sense that way given your desired results.

Comment: If I want to give a title to the whole list, do I insert a <LH>List title</LH> after the opening <ol> tag?

Comment: No, no such element exists (well it "did" for a while [about 20 years ago](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/listheader.html) but it never did really). You place a regular heading just before the opening `<ol>` tag.